# Can I store a soup in my cast-iron in the refrigerator for up to 24 hours in the cast-iron pot?

Tags: soup

Can I store a soup in my cast-iron pot for up to 24 hours in the refrigerator?

Comment: This question does not provide enough detail for us to answer it usefully.  What kind of soup?  Are you concerned about spoilage, flavor, or damage to the cast iron?  Please see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just to be clear, are you talking about a pot with a seasoned cast iron surface (no coating)?  Some cast iron pots are enameled on the inside, and they would not be reactive (and thus more suitable for storage).  Otherwise, see Lorel's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps there are some types of soup that would be ok, but many foods can easily pick up a metallic taste from cast iron if left in the pot overnight. Examples are tofu fried in a cast iron frying pan, egg omelet (egg sometimes even becomes gray), and anything tomatoey. I'm sure there are others, especially mildly flavored foods, and acidic ones.

So in general, rather than find out the hard way with your particular type of soup, I recommend changing containers for storage in the refrigerator.